# GridView in fragment is not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-gridview

getItem not going to called here is my code its is not working if i am use activity then its work properly but in fragment getItem method not gonna call please help

this is my Fragment:

```
public class HomeFragment extends BaseFragment{

    private static final String TAG = "HomeFragment";
    private GridView gvMainItems;
    private HomeFragmentGridAdapter homeFragmentGridAdapter;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false);
        gvMainItems = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gvMainItems);

        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 1; i < 100; i++){
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("item", String.valueOf(i));
            arrayList.add(map);
        }

        homeFragmentGridAdapter = new HomeFragmentGridAdapter(getActivity(), arrayList);
        gvMainItems.setAdapter(homeFragmentGridAdapter);

        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }
}
```

This is my adapter:

```
 public class HomeFragmentGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList;
    private ViewHolder holder;

    public HomeFragmentGridAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> arrayList){
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return arrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View cinvertview, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        if(cinvertview == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            cinvertview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_grid_raw, null, true);
            holder.textView = (TextView) cinvertview.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            cinvertview.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) cinvertview.getTag();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "getItem: "+arrayList.get(position).get("item"));

        holder.textView.setText(arrayList.get(position).get("item"));
        return cinvertview;
    }
    public class ViewHolder{

        public ImageView ivGridItem;
        public TextView textView;
    }
}
```

this is xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/content_main" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical" 
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" 
tools:context="com.neodocto.activity.MainActivity" 
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"> 



<GridView android:id="@+id/gvMainItems" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:columnWidth="90dp" 
android:gravity="center" 
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp" 
android:numColumns="auto_fit" 
android:stretchMode="columnWidth" 
android:verticalSpacing="10dp" 
/> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This happens also if your HomeFragment extends Fragment instead of BaseFragment ?

Comment: yes same in Fragment also

Comment: @DharaPatel which error you get?

Comment: getItem() method in adapter not gonna call and nothing going to print in gridview

Comment: @DharaPatel please change your adapter

Comment: i tried i have deleted old one and create new but not working if i put code in activity its working properly

Comment: @DharaPatel just a wait while a few min i have post adapter code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135183/discussion-between-hardik-parmar-and-dhara-patel).

Comment: I've implemented it (extending Fragment not BaseFragment) and it's working. I suggest you to post the code of your layout(s), because the problems seem to be there

Comment: It's working well. Can you also post the code of the main (the activity in which the fragment lives) layout?

Comment: this is code of calling fragment

Comment: removeAllFragment(new SettingFragment(), false, AndyConstants.HOMEFRAGMENT);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));

Comment: May be you are overriding the `item` key in the  `map.put("item", String.valueOf(i));` Change this  `map.put("item" + i, String.valueOf(i));` and try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change my gridview to this and it working

```
<GridView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/gvMainItems"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:numColumns="4" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this code in your `HomeFragment` :

```
homeFragmentGridAdapter = new HomeFragmentGridAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), arrayList);
```

Because Your construct uses a Context instead of an FragmentActivity (returned by the `getActivity()`.

Comment: i change getActivity().getApplicationContext() but not working

Answer (score 1):

Please try on this way i have work fine
Change on your adapter like

```
private final Context context;
private final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList;
private ViewHolder holder;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public HomeFragmentGridAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View cinvertview, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    if (cinvertview == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        cinvertview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_purchase_items, null);

        holder.textView = (TextView) cinvertview.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        cinvertview.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) cinvertview.getTag();
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "getItem: " + arrayList.get(position).get("item"));

    holder.textView.setText(arrayList.get(position).get("item"));
    return cinvertview;
}

public class ViewHolder {

    public ImageView ivGridItem;
    public TextView textView;
}
```

Comment: xml file change which you gave